# Error creating javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore in NetBeans 6.0

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, ioexception, recordstore

I'm trying to write an application with J2ME that uses `javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore` to store persistent data. I'm developing this project in NetBeans 6.0 and J2ME 2.2 on Gentoo. When I try to run the project, I get an error because apparently the record store can't be created. Here's a sample of output including the stack trace:

```
jar:
pre-run:
cldc-run:
Copying 1 file to /home/dzaslavs/ellipsix/programming/cataschedule/dist/nbrun1623864904410254936
Copying 1 file to /home/dzaslavs/ellipsix/programming/cataschedule/dist/nbrun1623864904410254936
Jad URL for OTA execution: http://localhost:8082/servlet/org.netbeans.modules.mobility.project.jam.JAMServlet/home/dzaslavs/ellipsix/programming/cataschedule/dist//CATASchedule.jad
Starting emulator in execution mode
Running with storage root rms
javax.microedition.rms.RecordStoreException: error opening record store file
        at javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore.(RecordStore.java:2150)
        at javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore.openRecordStore(RecordStore.java:208)
        at net.ellipsix.cata.StopRecordStore.(StopRecordStore.java:48)
        at net.ellipsix.cata.CATAMIDlet.getStopList(CATAMIDlet.java:169)
        at net.ellipsix.cata.CATAMIDlet.startMIDlet(CATAMIDlet.java:64)
        at net.ellipsix.cata.CATAMIDlet.startApp(CATAMIDlet.java:449)
        at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletProxy.startApp(MIDletProxy.java:44)
        at com.sun.midp.midlet.Scheduler.schedule(Scheduler.java:372)
        at com.sun.midp.main.Main.runLocalClass(Main.java:461)
        at com.sun.midp.main.Main.main(Main.java:126)
```

I've found a link to what I *think* is the source of `RecordStore`, where the exception is being thrown: http://jcs.mobile-utopia.com/jcs/78052_RecordStore.java.  The relevant line is down near the bottom, basically like this:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
    ...
    throw new RecordStoreException("error opening record store " + 
                                       "file");
}
```

so that suggests that there is an IOException triggered when NetBeans tries to create the record store file.  But why would that happen? The output is unfortunately silent on exactly why the record store creation is failing. Does anyone know what might be going wrong, or anything about how NetBeans handles `RecordStore`s internally?

Here's the constructor from my code in which the error is triggered, if it's relevant:

```
public StopRecordStore() throws RecordStoreException {
    this.store = RecordStore.openRecordStore("freqstops", true);
    if (store.getNumRecords() == 0) {
        try {
            byte[] collegeAllen = new StopRecord((short)1, "College & Allen").toBytes();
            store.addRecord(collegeAllen, 0, collegeAllen.length);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } // do nothing
    }
}
```

*EDIT*: ...no answers after 10 hours?  Really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran

```
strace netbeans-6.0
```

and watched for filenames appearing in the output around the time when the application threw an error.

```
[pid 10593] stat64("/opt/sun-j2me-bin-2.2/bin/./../appdb/rms/run_by_class_storage_freqstops.db", 0xbfa475c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 10593] open("/opt/sun-j2me-bin-2.2/bin/./../appdb/rms", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|0x80000) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 10593] stat64("/opt/sun-j2me-bin-2.2/bin/./../appdb/rms", 0xbfa475d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 10593] mkdir("/opt/sun-j2me-bin-2.2/bin/./../appdb/rms", 0777) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Manually creating the directory `/opt/sun-j2me-bin-2.2/appdb/rms` and `chmod`ding it to 0777 solved the problem.